# Pronoun usage in "Did you enjoy his playing the violin?"

Tags: grammar, pronouns, possessives, possessive-pronouns

Why is the pronoun "his" used in this sentence?

"Did you enjoy his playing the violin?"

Comment: What scenario do you think the sentence describes?

Comment: Yeah. It **is** a rather strange way to ask the question. **Which** "playing of the violin"? Normally one would say _Did you enjoy his song/solo/concert?_, or if you were concentrating on his talent instead of the addressee's enjoyment, _How did you like the way he played?_

Comment: Look up “gerund”

Answer (score 2):

"His" is the subject of the gerund "singing." Typically the subject of a gerund is written as an accusative:

> Did you enjoy **him** playing the violin?

However, formal usage guides and overzealous English teachers will insist on using the possessive:

> Did you enjoy **his** playing the violin?

Comment: Yes. There's two complementizers for gerund clauses, called ACC-_ing_ and POSS-_ing_, because the pronouns are either accusative (_him_) or possessive (_his_). There's no difference, just a speaker's choice.

Comment: Did you enjoy his violin playing?

Comment: @WeatherVane In "his violin playing," "playing" is a deverbal noun rather than a gerund. For instance, only gerunds can be modified by adverbs: "him excellently playing the violin," but not "his excellently violin playing." This is because "violin" is a noun adjunct, which cannot modify a verb, so "violin playing" forces the deverbal noun interpretation of "playing."

Comment: I did not say it was a gerund: 'violin playing' is a noun phrase. Nor did I use an adverb.

Comment: Yeah, I was just clarifying to avoid confusing the asker.

Comment: Yes, the choice between accusative "him playing the guitar" and genitive "his playing the guitar" is mainly one of style. The genitive is characteristic of a fairly formal style and is most likely with personal pronouns, and next most likely with short singular NPs denoting humans.